# Can i make an android app using XML/JSON?

Tags: android, xml, json

I am just writing to ask whether or not it is possible to write an android app in XML/JSON? And if so is it possible to import a folder of XML/JSON into Eclipse (another IDE) and have a working app?

Comment: Are you sure you mean xml and json? You should probably google them.

Answer (score 4):

No.

XML and JSON are data formats.

You need a programming language to write an application.

(Technically, XSLT is a turing complete language that is an application of XML … but I doubt it would suit your needs)

Comment: why are there json plugins for eclipse then?

Comment: whats the difference between data formats and programming language

Comment: if i could convert the xml to xslt would it work?

Comment: Presumably the JSON plugins for eclipse provide syntax highlighting for the data format. A data format describes a set of data. A programming language expresses instructions. You can't convert arbitrary XML to XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an app with no programming language knowledge using http://mobileroadie.com/, I have never used it before so I can't really tell you anything about it but I know you cannot create an android app with just XML or JSON!